# How to assign xml node value to bash script variable

Tags: xml, bash, shell

I have a valid xml file which contains something like:

```
  <ConfigSettings>
    <pairs>
        <p>
            <Name>InstallDirectory</Name>
            <Val>/Library/Application Support/Home</Val>
        </p>
```

... other pairs follow ...

On the command line the following works to return the correct `<Val>` string:

```
echo 'cat /ConfigureSDK/ConfigSettings/pairs/p[Name="InstallDirectory"]/Val/text()' | xmllint --shell initsdk.xml | grep -v "^/ >"
```

However, when I try to assign the result to a variable within a script, e.g.,

```
ABC='cat /ConfigureSDK/ConfigSettings/pairs/p[Name="InstallDirectory"]/Val/text()' | xmllint --shell initsdk.xml | grep -v "^/ >"
```

then try

```
echo $ABC
```

nothing is printed.

I'm sure I'm missing something simple, but I have tried many variations to no avail.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `export` and `$(...)` for capturing the output of a command.

```
$ export A=$(echo Hello)
$ echo $A
Hello
```

Comment: Ignore the -1 I don't know what I'm doing Re voting, I was trying to give an up vote.  Anyway, this certainly is the correct answer.

Comment: @user3444281 I'll edit the answer slightly, then you should be able to change your vote to an up vote.